# Broadcast storm (широковещательный шторм) в сети

Tags: сеть, коммутатор

День добрый. Подскажите как правильно боротся с широковещательным штормом? На коммутаторе есть функция - Storm-control, у которой по умолчанию на каждый порт выставлено значение 100%. Что означают эти 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

Strorm control обычно задаётся через количество пакетов бродкаста проходящих через интерфейс. 100% скорее всего отношение юникаст трафика к бродкасту или максимальная утилизация интерфейса. Лучше посмотреть в документации к оборудованию.